# Sound Manager 2 basic example redirect problem (mp3 on separate page)

Tags: javascript, audio, mouseover, html5-audio, soundmanager2

I'm trying to implement the following Audio w/ Sound Manager2 example:

www. shillmania/ projects/ soundmanager2/ demo/ play-mp3-links/ basic.html

I thought I had all the files correctly linked as the debug information is checking out,
but the page is redirecting me to a quicktime link in a separate page.

The documentations states: "SoundManager 2 intercepts clicks to MP3 links and plays them inline. The script assigns additional CSS classes to the links to indicate their state (playing/paused, etc.)"

1. What am I missing?
2. Can I replace the click events with mouseover events within inline.js?  Or would that require a major re-write?  My goal is to play a quick sound effect on mouseover events on my menus across all browsers with fallbacks.

   http://www.canvaskit.com/audio_html5/

I appreciate any input, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it's not working because the `soundManager` settings are being made twice: once in `inlineplayer.js`...

```
soundManager.debugMode = true; // disable or enable debug output
soundManager.useFlashBlock = true;
soundManager.url = '../../swf/'; // path to directory containing SM2 SWF

// optional: enable MPEG-4/AAC support (requires flash 9)

soundManager.flashVersion = 9;
soundManager.useMovieStar = true;

// ----

soundManager.onready(function() {
  if (soundManager.supported()) {
    // soundManager.createSound() etc. may now be called
    inlinePlayer = new InlinePlayer();
  }
});
```

...and again inline with the HTML itself:

```
soundManager.url = 'soundmanager/swf/';
soundManager.flashVersion = 9; // optional: shiny features (default = 8)
soundManager.useFlashBlock = true; // optionally, enable when you're ready to dive in
// enable HTML5 audio support, if you're feeling adventurous. iPad/iPhone will always get this.
//soundManager.useHTML5Audio = true;

// (cut)

soundManager.onready(function() {
  if (soundManager.supported()) {
    alert('Yay, SM2 loaded OK!');   
  } else {
    alert('Oh snap, SM2 could not start.');
  }
});
```

The settings conflict, and I imagine that `soundManager.url` from the HTML is correct but everything else should come from `inlineplayer.js`. Edit as necessary until each parameter is only set once.

Comment: I downloaded a clean version and started from scratch with the demo files, which also work on my local server.  The duplication was the problem, and I'm digging into the documentation to see about using this library for hover effects.  If anyone knows any other JS audio libraries please let me know!!  Thanks!!